# R - new line in paste() function

Tags: r, line, newline, paste

How can we insert a new line when using the function [paste()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/paste.html) or any function that concatenates strings in R?

There are many web pages on this topic but none answers clearly or gives a solution that works. I precise I don't want to use the function [cat](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cat.html), I need to work with string of characters.
Here are all my attempts (derived from all the suggestions on from different forum), they all fail...

#### 1st Try: paste()

```
msg <- "==================================================\n"
msg <- paste(msg, "Var:")
print(msg)
```

Output:

> [1] "==================================================\n Var:"

#### 2nd Try: paste0()

```
msg <- "==================================================\n"
msg <- paste0(msg, "Var:")
print(msg)
```

Output:

> [1] "==================================================\nVar:"

#### 3rd Try: sep

```
msg <- "=================================================="
msg <- paste(msg, "Var:", sep = "\n")
print(msg)
```

Output:

> [1] "==================================================\nVar:"

#### 4th Try: sprintf

```
msg <- sprintf("==================================================\n")
msg <- paste(msg, "Var:")
print(msg)
```

Output:

> [1] "==================================================\nVar:"

I believe I've tried everything I could... If you have an idea?!

Comment: The only thing you didn't show there is the output that you actually **do** want.  Try `cat`

Comment: You say "I don't want to use `cat`." Why? It takes a string of characters...

Answer (score 13):

You could try `strsplit`

```
msg <- "==================================================\n"
msg2 <- paste(msg, "Var:")
strsplit(msg2, "\n")[[1]]
# [1] "=================================================="
# [2] " Var:"
```

This can also be used with `noquote` if you don't want quotes.

```
noquote(strsplit(msg2, "\n")[[1]])
# [1] ==================================================
# [2]  Var:
```

This produces virtually the same result as if you were to use `print` with `quote = FALSE`

You can also define your own print method

```
print.myClass <- function(x, ...)  strsplit(x, "\n")[[1]]
class(msg2) <- "myClass"
print(msg2)
# [1] "=================================================="
# [2] " Var:"
```

Comment: Thank for @RichardScriven but this is not really what I want.

Comment: Well what *do* you want?