# R - Insert newline in a variable (not for printing purposes)

Tags: r

So here's the problem
There's a requirement to input newline (to process URL),

Basically it's like this in Python:

```
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring
```

I have tried using `paste` but whenever I use "\n" this character is included in the string.

I know a lot of people recommended `cat` but cat is for printing purposes, therefore you can make it into a variable such as

```
canonical_request <- cat(method, "\n", canonical_uri, "\n", canonical_querystring)
```

if you call canonical_request this way, it will give `NULL`

Do you know how to insert newline (by concatenating characters) in R?

ps. it's different from question here:
[R - new line in paste() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022378/r-new-line-in-paste-function)
(OP doesn't state clearly the purposes of new line usage, I'm assuming it's for printing purposes)

Comment: I think this could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112786/how-to-split-the-main-title-of-a-plot-in-2-or-more-lines

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - new line in paste() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022378/r-new-line-in-paste-function)

Comment: `paste` does exactly what you want. You simply misinterpret the output when printing it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see, i get your point now. thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as you mentioned `cat()` is used for printing puposes. It interpretes "\n" as a linebreak, but does not return you a concenated character. Therefore to concenate the character you could use `paste()` and then call `cat()` to print it:

```
method = "method"
canonical_uri = "canonical_uri"
canonical_querystring = "querystring"
out <- paste(method, "\n", canonical_uri, "\n", canonical_querystring,sep = "")
cat(out)
```